# Best way to initialize three dimension List

Tags: java, arraylist, initialization

Is there a better way that allows me to initialize three-dimensional ArrayList?

```
List<List<List<String>>> lista = new ArrayList<List<List<String>>>(3);  
for (int i=0;i<3;i++){  
    List<List<String>> lista2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>(4);  
    for (int j=0;j<4;j++)lista2.add(new ArrayList<String>(5));
    lista.add(lista2);
}
```

Comment: If I were about to use a similar structure multiple times, I'd wrap it in a new class which'd provide appropriate constructors and methods to handle it more intuitively.

Comment: Do you really need a list in a list in a list? Sometimes its better to write a class holding nothing but a list. This list could contain other classes with a lists in them etc ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without external libraries or introducing new classes -- you can use the [Double Brace Initialization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization). It is a bit cleaner than having intermediate variables.

```
public List<List<List<String>>> lista = new ArrayList<List<List<String>>>(){{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        add(new ArrayList<List<String>>(){{
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                add(new ArrayList<>(5));
        }});
}};
```

Comment: Good idea, it's the same but more clear.. For the moment the best solution.